# Extend sails 0.10 grunt set-up

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I am intending to add a task to sails's (0.10 rc5) grunt build system.

**tasks/config/asset-versioning.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.config.set('asset-versioning', {
    copy: {
      src: '.tmp/public/min/production.js',
      dest: '.tmp/public/min/production2.js'
    }
  });

  grunt.task.registerTask('asset-versioning', ['copy']);

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

**tasks/register/prod.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('prod', [
        'compileAssets',
        'concat',
        'uglify',
        'cssmin',
        'sails-linker:prodJs',
        'sails-linker:prodStyles',
        'sails-linker:devTpl',
        'asset-versioning' // Added the task config here
    ]);
};
```

After running `sails lift --prod --verbose` I am getting following error:

```
Grunt :: Warning: Task "asset-versioning" not found.
** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
```

**What am I missing?**

---

**EDIT**

Apparently I am missing to register my task.

Adding `grunt.task.registerTask('asset-versioning');` to the first file. I am not getting any error, but my task is not running! Nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you're having this all mixed up. Copy is a predefined task, you just need to tweak its configs. Go to tasks/config/copy.js and add your custom configuration (in the grunt.config.set call)

```
productionfiles: {
  src: '.tmp/public/min/production.min.js',
  dest: '.tmp/public/min/production2.min.js'
}
```

Then, in the tasks/register/prod.js, make sure you call copy:productionfiles, and it will do the magic.

**Copy.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('copy', {
        dev: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './assets',
                src: ['**/*.!(coffee|less)'],
                dest: '.tmp/public'
            }]
        },
        build: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/public',
                src: ['**/*'],
                dest: 'www'
            }]
        },
    productionfiles: {
      src: '.tmp/public/min/production.min.js',
      dest: '.tmp/public/min/production2.min.js'
    }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

**Prod.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('prod', [
        'compileAssets',
        'concat',
        'uglify',
        'cssmin',
        'sails-linker:prodJs',
        'sails-linker:prodStyles',
        'sails-linker:devTpl',
        'sails-linker:prodJsJade',
        'sails-linker:prodStylesJade',
        'sails-linker:devTplJade',
        'copy:productionfiles'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Ultimatively I want to rename a file and its reference inside another file. So I would need to do all that in a separate task from copy. Is that possible?

Comment: Use the sails-linker task if you want the reference to automatically change. Make a function called sails-linker:productionfiles that will do that for you.